# Using i18n for internalization

Tags: angular, internationalization

I used i18n for translation my app, but when I loaded my app I got error :

```
GET http://localhost:4200/i18n/fr.json 404 (Not Found)
```

I added json file (fr, de) in folder assets/i18n/fr.json and assets/i18n/de.json.

My code in component.ts

```
 constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.addLangs(["de", "fr"]);
    translate.setDefaultLang('fr');

    let browserLang = translate.getBrowserLang();
    console.log(browserLang);
    translate.use(browserLang.match(/fr|de/) ? browserLang : 'fr');
  }
```

Where can I add the json file for resolve it ?

Comment: Do you use the built-in i18n or an external library ?

Comment: I don't use an external library .. i18n is now native in angular 2/4 I think ? or not ?   In package.json I have : ` "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }, `

Comment: It is, but not like that. Maybe you should read [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@feloy/deploying-an-i18n-angular-app-with-angular-cli-fc788f17e358) or even the [official one](https://angular.io/guide/i18n). You can also read the [angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-internationalization) which makes it so easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can import your `.json` files on top of your `i18n.service` file like so:

```js
import de from 'assets/i18n/de.json';
import fr from 'assets/i18n/fr.json';
```